# Flow cannot decide which case to select in intersection type when iterating over Immutable.Record

Tags: javascript, flowtype, immutable.js

```
// @flow
import type {RecordOf} from 'immutable';


function foo<T: {[string]: string}>(state: RecordOf<T>) {
  for (let [key, value] of state) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
}
```

In the code above, the `for...of` loop causes a flow type error: 
`$Iterable. Could not decide which case to select intersection type`.

I assume that is because immutable.js defines `RecordOf` as `type RecordOf<Values: Object> = RecordInstance<Values> & Values;`. However, `RecordInstance` is not exported, so how do I tell flow that `state` is indeed a `RecordInstance` and can be iterated over like this?